# Conditionally Change Value in Time Series Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a data set like:

```
time    team      amount    set
----------------------------------
1:00    A         100       [X,Y,Z]
2:00    B         50        [X,Y,Z]
3:00    C         40        [X,Y,Z]
4:00    D         25        [X,Y,Z]
5:00    E         30        [X,Y,Z]
6:00    X         75        [X,Y,Z]
```

Any time `amount` = 25, I want to add the value in `team` to the running list in `set`, if it's 75, I want to remove them. Expected output here would be:

```
time    team      amount    set
----------------------------------
1:00    A         100       [X,Y,Z]
2:00    B         50        [X,Y,Z]
3:00    C         40        [X,Y,Z]
4:00    D         25        [X,Y,Z,D]
5:00    E         30        [X,Y,Z,D]
6:00    X         75        [Y,Z,D]
```

I am able to achieve this by iterating through the dataframe and using conditional logic, but I would think there is a more efficient way?

Comment: I put together a better and more relevant example here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666084/create-and-maintain-system-state-based-on-action), I'm going to delete this question